# how to store web activity result in a variable?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-devops-rest-api, powerbi-rest-api

i have a web activity through which i am executing a rest API(execute queries)
this is a sample output of that:

```
        {

         "results": [
             {
             "tables": [
                 {
                 "rows": [
                       {
                       "[Value]": "2022-10-25T00:00:00Z"
                       }
                      ]
                  }
             ]
         }
]
```

i want to store the date value inside [Value] in a variable in adf

(variable value should be:2022-10-25T00:00:00Z)

but i am not able to do that because of square brackets
this is what i have tried

```
"@activity('SQl validation').output.results[0].tables[0].rows[0].[value]"
```

but it give me error

```
Position 73 Unrecognized expression: value
```

please suggest how i can fix this

[image]

Comment: Edit the question to provide the error message as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Look at the following demonstration. I have the lookup which returns the following values.

[image]

- To access the `[companyId]` attribute from this output array, I have used the following dynamic content (Using for loop just for demonstration):

```
@string(activity('myLookUp').output.value[item()]['[companyId]'])
```

[image]

- So, you can use the following dynamic content instead:

```
@activity('SQl validation').output.results[0].tables[0].rows[0]['[value]']
```